# how to make a post request in yii without form?

Tags: php, api, yii

i want to send image in database using url. but it is sending null value. please guide me about this. i want to make an api which will be use to upload image

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $model = new Users;

    if(isset($_POST['Users']))
    {
       $model->image=$_POST['Users']['image'];

        $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
         echo $model->image;
        echo 'hello';
        if(is_object($model->image)){
            //mkdir(getcwd().'/images/users/' . $model->id."/");
            $name = getcwd().'/images/' .$model->id."/".$model->image->getName();

            $model->image->saveAs($name);
            try{
            $image = Yii::app()->image->load($name);
            $image->resize(50, 50);
            $image->save();
            }
            catch(Exception $ex ){
                 echo 'image has been saved successfully';
            die;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use the superglobal array $_POST without a form

Comment: what should i do to make it a post request??

Comment: create a form to upload the file

Comment: @RimshaFatima, where do you get an image from: file system? db?

Comment: i want to save image in database

Comment: don't forget to put `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',` in your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler the better...
I think you'd better use standard Yii `fileField()` in form.

### In view:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
 'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
 'enableClientValidation'=>false,
 'htmlOptions' => array(
    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
 ),
)); ?>
...

<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image'); ?> 
<?php echo $form->fileField($model,'image',array('size'=>40,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'image'); ?>
<br><br>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton(  Yii::t('general','Create')  ); ?>

<?php  // show image if it already exists in file system
 if ((getimagesize(Yii::app()->basePath. '/../img/foto/'. $model->article . '.jpg') !== false) ) : ?> 
<?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl. '/img/foto/'. $model->article . '.jpg')?> 
<?php endif;    ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Notice `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'` in the form html settings. This makes it to upload file.
Then on a controller side you apply your file catch and store

As far as a model side I recommend to closely follow [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/).

If you try to do smth. **without form** you'll waste time inventing bycicle.